# Can CoreData models be exported to use in another app?

Tags: iphone, core-data, export

Is there any way to export a CoreData model file (i.e entities description: *.xcdatamodeld) to another project. Because re-recreate all entities is boring :-)

Comment: ...in what context are you talking?

Comment: Oh sorry, I mean, I have an app say for iPhone and I want to start from scratch an iPad one. I'd like to import my CoreData entities from my iPhone project into the new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just add/copy the model file itself to the new project just like you would any other type of file. . You can even add/copy an existing store if the apps use the same initial data. I do this all the time

Comment: Ok thanks! I thaugh I did test this, but didn't succeed, will try again!

Comment: You can even link multiple projects to the same model file so that when that model changes all of the projects will see it.

Comment: @MarcusS.Zarra hello Marcus, can you please give some direction on how can we use same model file for multiple projects??

Comment: There is no additional direction required.  Just link the same file in every project and it will compile into the project just fine.